# Change color of notification icon like actual color of mediastyle notification bar

Tags: android, android-notification.mediastyle

I created mediaStyle Notification in my app. This notification is colored depending on the actual playing song. I set `.setColor(color)` in `NotificationCompat.Builder`so that I get also a colored program Icon while drawing the notification bar. This color is one of my program colors.

**What I want:**
How can I set the color of the program icon like the mediastyle notification color while drawing (swiping) the notification bar. I want to change the Icon color dynamically, depending on the actual notification color.

Is that possible?

Thanks,